# Define function only for a discrete set of values

Tags: functions

I want to define an indexed function $f$ with index $k$ over some arguments $m$. However, I only want to define the index for some set ${1,2,...,x}$ my approach was the following

```
For[k=1,k<x+1,k++,    
f[k,m_]:= g[k,m]
]
Clear[k]
```

However this seems not to define the function as

```
In[1]=f[3,n]
```

yields

```
Out[1]=g[k,n]
```

Is there another way to define $f$ as a function of $m$ but with index $k$ on the respective interval?

(Clarification: the original code has $k$ as an index-subscript, but I couldn't find how to do this here)

Comment: I don't understand. If you simply define `f[k_, m_] := g[k, m]` (without the loop) then whenever you ask for `f[3,n]` you will get `g[3,n]`. If you only want it defined for integers, then use `f[k_IntegerQ, m_] := g[k, m]`

Comment: Denoting by `list` the list of elements `{1, 2, ..., x}` (where `x` is given), you can do `f[k_Integer, m_] /; MemberQ[list, k] := g[k, m]`, or `MemberQ[Range[x], k]` (where `x` is given) if you're only considering a set of consecutive integers up to `x`.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You issue is, that the right hand side of your definition - the `g[k,m]` part - is not evaluated and the value of `k` is not inserted. You can see this by looking at a simple `Trace`:

```
ClearAll[f];

k = 1;
Trace[f[k, m_] := g[k, m]]
(* {f[k,m_]:=g[k,m],{{k,1},f[1,m_]},Null} *)
```

If you really want to follow your approach, you need to ensure, that the *value* of `k` is inserted, even if the rhs is not evaluated. This can be done using a pure function or `With`. I'm using `Array` or `Range` or `Table` to get rid of the ugly `For` loop. All three version should work, where the last one does indeed look funny:

```
ClearAll[f];
(f[#, m_] := g[#, m]) & /@ Range[10];

ClearAll[f];
Array[(f[#, m_] := g[#, m]) &, 10];

ClearAll[f];
Table[With[{i = i}, f[i, m_] := g[i, m]], {i, 10}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force a function to be defined for certain integer variable. For instance

```
f[x_,n_Integer]:= n Sin[x]
```

will be evaluated only if `n` is an integer

Try `f[2.34,3]` and `f[2.34, 3.2]` or even `f[2.34,3.]`

the two last function will not be evaluated